# Sitecore poll module sample code

Tags: sitecore, sample

I installed and configured the Poll Module to work fine. The website I am working on will have a Poll instance on a page either as a left rail or a right rail item. The Polls would be setup in a separate folder. On the page item there will be a multilist field which will point to the Polls folder and the user can select whichever poll they choose to. The folder will also contain different sublayouts which will could be selected to be displayed on the rail. I have some custom code which will look at the above mentioned multilist field and show these rail items.

I don't know how to display a Poll programmatically. I haven't found any code samples and also not sure where to set the sublayout. Should I set it on the Poll template itself and then let use code to display it? How can I achieve this in code? Any code samples would be helpful.

Comment: Very typical :). I answered, and already knew I wouldn't get any accepts on this one.

Comment: Nice one, does everything work now?

Comment: You only answer for them points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hoping that you will this time accept the answer, I wrote the following for you (based on the OMS Poll module:

Read out the field on your item:

```
 Sitecore.Data.Fields.ReferenceField selectedPoll = (Sitecore.Data.Fields.ReferenceField)Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["Poll"];
```

Get the pollItem:

```
 if (selectedPoll.TargetItem != null)
            {
                Item pollItem = selectedPoll.TargetItem;

                if (pollItem != null)
                {
```

Check if the poll is opened or closed and place:

```
 Sitecore.Data.Fields.CheckboxField pollClosed = (Sitecore.Data.Fields.CheckboxField)pollItem.Fields["Closed"];

                    if (pollClosed.Checked == false)
                    {
                        // Set the header of the snippetBlock
                        ltPollHeader.Text = pollItem.Name;

                        PollVotingSublayout pollSublayout = (PollVotingSublayout)LoadControl("/sitecore modules/Shell/Poll Module/Controls/PollVotingSublayout.ascx");
                        pollSublayout.Attributes.Add("sc_parameters", "PollPath=" + pollItem.Paths.FullPath);
                        pollSublayout.CurrentPoll = (PollItem)pollItem;
                        this.pollRegion.Controls.Add(pollSublayout);

                        phPollSnippet.Visible = true;

                        int blockPos = 0;

                        if (snippetField != null)
                        {
                            if (snippetField.GetItems().Any())
                            {
                                blockPos = 1;
                            }
                        }

                        string cssClass = String.Empty;

                        if (blockPos == 0)
                        {
                            cssClass = "snippetColHomeFirst";
                        }

                        this.SetClass("snippetColHome", cssClass);
                    }
```

Hope that you can make up something using this snippets. Good luck!

Comment: So I got the poll to work, but my numbers aren't getting updated. I have checked to see errors in firebug and I do not see any post errors. Any ideas?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a Poll account in User Manager. Do you maybe have details on what the permissions and roles this account is supposed to have?

Comment: There should be a user account called "poll" on the sitecore domain. This account is normally used internal by the poll. In the comment of this account is stated: "Please do not remove this account".

Answer (score 1):

There should be a user account called "poll" on the sitecore domain. This account is normally used internal by the poll. In the comment of this account is stated: "Please do not remove this account". the account should have the Sitecore Minimal Page Editor role. I don't know the poll user credentials, but you might find that by either using reflector or opening cs files that you can get by downloading the source.